# How to get around No element found in protractor tests?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have defined a protractor test which actually worked before but suddenly returns errors like:

```
  NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator:
```

When I pause the test before it tries to access the element like :

```
  element(by.id('lblhomeContent')).click();
```

When I inspect the html the id is present but not when the test runs. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, but [waiting for the element to be clickable](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable) might help:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions,
    elm = element(by.id('lblhomeContent'));

browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elm), 5000);

elm.click();
```